# Trying to import JSON file to be posted on API as soon as program runs

Tags: node.js

I'm building a food delivery web app where I need some items on my server. I want to import all this JSON data on server as soon as server is run. Then use axios to get it and update it in my cart component. How. do I import the JSON file and make sure all the items are placed into my own API

JSON FILE:

```
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "small burger",
    "price": 3.00
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "medium burger",
    "price": 4.20

},
{
    "id": 3,
    "name": "large burger",
    "price": 5.00
},
{
    "id": 4,
    "name":"medium drink",
    "price": 1.50
},
{
    "id": 5,
    "name":"large drink",
    "price": 2.00
},
{
    "id": 6,
    "name":"xl drink",
    "price": 2.50
},
{
    "id": 7,
    "name":"small fries",
    "price": 2.00
},
{
    "id": 8,
    "name":"medium fries",
    "price": 3.00
},
{
    "id": 9,
    "name":"large fries",
    "price": 4.00
}
```

]

SERVER/INDEX.JS

```
const app = express()
const bc = require('./controllers/foodCtrl')

const port = 4000

app.use(express.json())

app.get('/api/foods', bc.read)
app.post('/api/foods-in-cart', bc.create)
app.put('/api/foods-in-cart/:id', bc.update)
app.delete('/api/foods-in-cart/:id', bc.delete)

app.listen(port, () => console.log('Server running on ' + port))






SERVER/CONTROLLERS/foodCtrl.js

    // import * as foods from '.../food.json'
const food = []
let id = 1

module.exports = {

    read: (req, res) => {
        res.status(200).send(food)
    },
    
    create: (req, res) => {

        food.push(
            {
                id: id,
                name: req.body.name,
                price: req.body.price
            }
        )
        id++
        res.status(200).send(food)
    },

    update: (req, res) => {
        const {id} = req.params
        let foodIndex = 0
        food.map((element, index) => {
            if(element.id === +id){
                foodIndex = index
            }
        })
        let updateName = {
            id: +id,
            name: req.body.name,
            price: req.body.price
        }
        food.splice(foodIndex, 1, updateName)
        res.status(200).send(food)
    },
    delete: (req, res) => {
        const {id} = req.params
        let index2 = 0

        food.map((element, i) => {
            if(element.id === +id){
                index2 = i
            }
        })

        food.splice(index2, 1)
        res.status(200).send(food)
    }



}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very easy, you can just add `const food = require('./food.json');` on top of your `SERVER/CONTROLLERS/foodCtrl.js`.

The JSON will be loaded and parsed as Javascript object, and you are able to access it at `food`

You might ask why are we able to import JSON file directly? That is because node provide this function out of the box.

you can read more at https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_all_together

Comment: Love it! Thanks a bunch